# Good resources on how to program PEBS (Precise event based sampling) counters?

Tags: performance, memory, cpu, processor, perf

I have been trying to log all memory accesses of a program, which as I read seems to be impossible. I have been trying to see to what extent can I go to log at least a major portion of the memory accesses, if not all. So I was looking to program the PEBS counters in such a way that I could see changes in the number of memory access samples collected. I wanted to know if I can do this by modifying the counter-reset value of PEBS counters. (Usually this goes to zero, but I want to set it to a higher value)

So I was looking to program these PEBS counters on my own. Has anybody had experience manipulating the PEBS counters ? Specifically I was looking for good sources to see how to program them. I have gone through the Intel documentation and understood the steps. But I wanted to understand some sample programs. I have gone through the below github repo :-

https://github.com/pyrovski/powertools

But I am not quite sure, how and where to start. Are there any other good sources that I need to look ? Any suggestion for good resources to understand and start programming will be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging all memory accesses of any executable/process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080947/logging-all-memory-accesses-of-any-executable-process-in-linux). Please, don't open new questions, but **explain why you want to have no overhead** and do it in already opened questions. You should do 2 runs: one to do the timing measurement without memory logging and other with memory logging and any overhead. What do you want to log: only memory address & sequence, or timing too. Why you think you need all/every/ 50% / 10% / 5 % of all memory accesses, for what?

Comment: Hi @osgx, I am only interested in logging all the memory addresses, I do not need the sequence. I have tried various methods - specifically I tried to use andi-kleen's pmu tools. We are actually trying to see if it is actually possible to log all of the memory accesses , if not, till what extent can we go to. Also we are not interested in using any dynamic binary instrumentation tools - we want to see if logging can be done with low overheads.

Comment: "log all memory accesses of a program" is possible with great overhead. Use compiler instrumentation or dynamic binary instrumentation, or some special hardware like PT/PEBS. Logging every access will have overhead (2x, 3x with good hw-based tracing, 10x-50x slowdown with tools like Valgrind). Logging 10% or 1% of memory requests (sampling more of hw tracing PEBS/PT) will have less overhead. Logging only L3 cache misses have less overhead, logging every request to L1 cache has greater overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Please, don't mix tracing and timing measurements in single run**.

It is *just impossible* both to have fastest run of Spec and all memory accesses traced. Do one run for timing and other (longer,slower) for memory access tracing.

---

In https://github.com/pyrovski/powertools the frequency of collected events is controlled by reset_val argument of `pebs_init`:

https://github.com/pyrovski/powertools/blob/0f66c5f3939a9b7b88ec73f140f1a0892cfba235/msr_pebs.c#L72

```
void
pebs_init(int nRecords, uint64_t *counter, uint64_t *reset_val ){
    // 1. Set up the precise event buffering utilities.
    //  a.  Place values in the
    //      i.   precise event buffer base,
    //      ii.  precise event index
    //      iii. precise event absolute maximum,
    //      iv.  precise event interrupt threshold,
    //      v.   and precise event counter reset fields
    //      of the DS buffer management area.
    //
    // 2.  Enable PEBS.  Set the Enable PEBS on PMC0 flag 
    //  (bit 0) in IA32_PEBS_ENABLE_MSR.
    //
    // 3.  Set up the IA32_PMC0 performance counter and 
    //  IA32_PERFEVTSEL0 for an event listed in Table 
    //  18-10.

    // IA32_DS_AREA points to 0x58 bytes of memory.  
    // (11 entries * 8 bytes each = 88 bytes.)

    // Each PEBS record is 0xB0 byes long.
...
    pds_area->pebs_counter0_reset       = reset_val[0];
    pds_area->pebs_counter1_reset       = reset_val[1];
    pds_area->pebs_counter2_reset       = reset_val[2];
    pds_area->pebs_counter3_reset       = reset_val[3];
...

    write_msr(0, PMC0, reset_val[0]);
    write_msr(1, PMC1, reset_val[1]);
    write_msr(2, PMC2, reset_val[2]);
    write_msr(3, PMC3, reset_val[3]);
```

This project is library to access PEBS, and there are no examples of its usage included in project (as I found there is only one [disabled test](https://github.com/tpatki/patki-power/blob/cfc93acb488c5b29deadabd769b091fba795f857/rapl/libmsr/msr_common.c#L86) in other projects by tpatki).

**Check [intel SDM Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) Vol 3B (this is the only good resource for PEBS programming)** for meaning of the fields and PEBS configuration and output:
https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-734.html

> 18.15.7 Processor Event-Based Sampling
>
> PEBS permits the saving of precise architectural information associated with one or more performance events in the precise event records buffer, which is part of the DS save area (see Section 17.4.9, “BTS and DS Save Area”). 
>   To use this mechanism, a counter is configured to overflow after it has counted a preset number of events. After the counter overflows, the processor copies the current state of the general-purpose and EFLAGS registers and instruction pointer into a record in the precise event records buffer. The processor then resets the count in the performance counter and restarts the counter. When the precise event records buffer is nearly full, an interrupt is  generated, allowing the precise event records to be saved. A circular buffer is not supported for precise event 
>   records.
>   ... After the PEBS-enabled counter has overflowed, PEBS 
>   record is recorded

(So, reset value is probably negative, equal to -1000 to get every 1000th event, -10 to get every 10th event. Counter will increment and PEBS is written at counter overflow.)

and https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-656.html  18.4.4  Processor Event Based Sampling (PEBS) "Table 18-10" - only L1/L2/DTLB misses have PEBS event in Intel Core. (Find PEBS section for your CPU and search for memory events. PEBS-capable events are really rare.)

So, to have more event recorded you probably want to set `reset` part of this function to smaller absolute value, like -50 or -10. With PEBS this may work (and try `perf -e cycles:upp -c 10` - don't ask to profile kernel  with so high frequency, only user-space `:u` and ask for precise with `:pp` and ask for -10 counter with `-c 10`. perf has all PEBS mechanics implemented both for MSR and for buffer parsing).

**Another good resource for PMU (hardware performance monitoring unit) are also from Intel, PMU Programming Guides**. They have short and compact description both of usual PMU and PEBS too. There is public "Nehalem Core PMU", most of it still useful for newer CPUs - https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/5/2/c/f/1/30320-Nehalem-PMU-Programming-Guide-Core.pdf (And there are uncore PMU guides: E5-2600 Uncore PMU  Guide, 2012 https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/design-guides/xeon-e5-2600-uncore-guide.pdf)

External pdf about PEBS: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Herath-These-Are-Not-Your-Grand-Daddys-CPU-Performance-Counters-CPU-Hardware-Performance-Counters-For-Security.pdf#page=23 PMCs: Setting Up for PEBS - from "Black Hat USA 2015 - These are Not Your Grand Daddy's CPU Performance Counters"

---

You may start from **short and simple program** (not the ref inputs of recent SpecCPU) and **use `perf` linux tool** (perf_events) to find acceptable ratio of memory requests recorded to all memory requests. PEBS is used with `perf` by adding `:p` and `:pp` suffix to the event specifier `record -e event:pp`. Also try [pmu-tools ocperf.py](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/blob/master/ocperf.py) for easier intel event name encoding.

Try to find the real (maximum) overhead with different recording ratios (1% / 10% / 50%) on the memory tests like (worst case of memory recording overhead, left part on the [Arithmetic Intensity scale](https://crd.lbl.gov/assets/Uploads/FTG/Projects/Roofline/_resampled/ResizedImage600300-rooflineai.png) of [Roofline model](https://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline/) - STREAM is BLAS1, GUPS and memlat are almost SpMV; real tasks are usually not so left on the scale):

- [STREAM test (linear access to memory)](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/),
- RandomAccess (GUPS) test
- some memory latency test ([memlat of 7z](http://www.7-cpu.com/utils.html), [lat_mem_rd](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_mem_rd.8.html) of [lmbench](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/)).

Do you want to trace every load/store commands or you only want to record requests that missed all (some) caches and were sent to main RAM memory of PC (to L3)?

Why you want no overhead and all memory accesses recorded? It is just impossible as every memory access have tracing of several bytes to be recorded to the memory. So, having memory tracing enabled (more than 10% or mem.access tracing) clearly will limit available memory bandwidth and the program will run slower. Even 1% tracing can be noted, but it effect (overhead) is smaller.

Your  CPU E5-2620 v4 is Broadwell-EP 14nm so it may have also some earlier variant of the Intel PT: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/18/processor-tracing https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/intel-pt.txt https://github.com/01org/processor-trace and especially Andi Kleen's blog on [pt](http://halobates.de/blog/p/category/pt): http://halobates.de/blog/p/410 "Cheat sheet for Intel Processor Trace with Linux perf and gdb"

> PT support in hardware: Broadwell (5th generation Core, Xeon v4)  More overhead. No fine grained timing.

PS: Scholars who study SpecCPU for memory access worked with memory access dumps/traces, and dumps were generated slowly:

- http://www.bu.edu/barc2015/abstracts/Karsli_BARC_2015.pdf - LLC misses recorded to offline analysis, no timing was recorded from tracing runs
- http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~ljohn/teaching/382m-15/reading/gove.pdf - all load/stores instrumented by writing into additional huge tracing buffer to periodic (rare) online aggregation. Such instrumentation is from 2x slow or slower, especially for memory bandwidth / latency limited core.
- http://www.jaleels.org/ajaleel/publications/SPECanalysis.pdf (by Aamer Jaleel of Intel Corporation, VSSAD) - Pin-based instrumentation - program code was modified and instrumented to write memory access metadata into buffer. Such instrumentation is from 2x slow or slower, especially for memory bandwidth / latency limited core. The paper lists and explains instrumentation overhead and Caveats:

> **Instrumentation Overhead**: Instrumentation involves
>   injecting extra code dynamically or statically into the
>   target application. The additional code causes an
>   application to spend extra time in executing the original
>   application ... Additionally, for multi-threaded
>   applications, instrumentation can modify the ordering of
>   instructions executed between different threads of the
>   application. As a result, IDS with multi-threaded
>   applications comes at the lack of some fidelity
>
> **Lack of Speculation**: Instrumentation only observes
>   instructions executed on the correct path of execution. As
>   a result, IDS may not be able to support wrong-path ...
>
> **User-level Traffic Only**: Current binary instrumentation
>   tools only support user-level instrumentation. Thus,
>   applications that are kernel intensive are unsuitable for
>   user-level IDS.

Comment: Thanks @osgx, for a detailed answer. I have used andi-kleen's pmu-tools to get a reference PEBS driver - I am trying to modify the pebs counter reset value (I am thinking to modify the reset value to a less negative value). And then try to load the driver module. How did you conclude that the reset counter value is negative ? A positive value could also overflow, couldn't it.

Comment: Also why do you suggest I only record user-space addresses ? I have noticed that if I record kernel-space addresses, most of the addresses logged are usually the same. Why is that so ?

Comment: Kalita, please show some of your perf commands (PT/PEBS/mem or anything).  Without PEBS/PT (which buffer samples by hardware into some memory place) you can't ask for extremely low count before interrupt: it will interrupt to soon after counting enabling and user code will have no chance to run (and may also deadlock the system). In theoretical computer science full of Turing machines and models with infinite memory/infinite time 64-bit counter will overflow. In real world with 4.3GHz CPU single 64bit counter incremented every tick may overflow in ... 2^32 seconds = 136 years (will not).

Comment: Hi @osgx, sorry for a late reply. I was trying various combinations with PEBS. Here is one of my commands :- `./perf record -e cpu/mem-stores/upp -c 1 ../../.././libquantum_base.arnab 100`. I specifically want to somehow avoid instrumentation to whichever limits possible.

Comment: Kalita, even without instrumentation, there is overhead of storing memory access information to some buffer, and the large buffer is in the RAM, consuming part of memory bw. It is still possible to record some fraction of memory accesses (don't know is it possible for all accesses), but program under record will run slower. Can you describe what is the goal of getting memory access samples, what your thesis is about?

Comment: Osgx, I agree, is it not possible to somehow record all memory access events and write into the buffer ? I want to reduce the number of interrupts. I am not preparing for any thesis. I want to see the extent of the system.